# Comparing tabs name

Tags: android, android-tabhost

does any body knows how can i compare current tab with another tab? Like

```
    if(tabhost.getCurrenttabtag().equals( tabhost.gettabtag() ))
```

i cannot find any answer :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String currentTabTag = tabhost.getCurrentTabTag();
if (currentTabTag.equals("Tab1")) {
   // do something
}
```

or you can compare the tab index int the OnTabChangedListener:

```
tabhost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

int i = getTabHost().getCurrentTab();
    switch(i) {
        case 1:
          break:
        case 2:
          break:
    }
  }
});
```